# Instantiate View Controller inside of navigation controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing. 
I have this scenario in my app. I have a main section of my app which is about 9 views all linked together with segues and one section that isn't linked to anything. This section needs to be instantiated from the app delegate when a certain condition is met.

I have one navigation controller, one at the start of section 2.

I need to be able to instantiate the second sections view controller while making it the root view controller for the second sections navigation controller.

at the minute I am getting the error:

```
push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by uinavigationcontroller
```

because I am only instantiating the view controller of section 2 and not making it the root view controller.

[screenshot links can be seen here as not enough rep to post screenshots.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fye2L.jpg)

When the app loads if a condition is met the section with the navigation controller is initiated, the user then has the option of transitioning to another view via a push segue. This is when I get the error.

It is transitioning in section two that returns the error.

code:

```
 if userDefaults.boolForKey("HasLaunchedOnce") == true {
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginSelection") as     LoginViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc

     }else {
        println("first launch")
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: So it breaks when you go to the `ResetPIN CodeVC` right? Also are you sure that `loginSelection` is the actual nav controller and not the vc labeled `Login View Controller`?

Comment: I tried them both. But having the storyboard ID on the nav controller causes a crash at launch.

Comment: Can you fill me in with the crash?

Comment: Aha! I figured it out, when I was casting the storyboard to be initiated I forgot to change the casting from the View Controller to the storyboard to the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not the problem The problem is, that your ViewController isn't embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

To resolve that, Click on the UIViewController which isn't embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Then click in the Xcode Menu:

```
Editor-> Embed in -> Navigationcontroller.
```

Comment: No it's embedded in. I'll add a screenshot now.